# FlexSlider touch not working on iphone but working fine in andorid

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider

Slider working fine on desktop browser and android devices but in iphone touch to move next/prec image not working. Though by clicking on next prev button is working fine.

HTML Code

```
<div class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
    <li class="li0"><a href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="1.jpg"></img></a></li>
    <li class="li1"><a href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="9.jpg"></img></a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

JQuery

```
 $(".flexslider").flexslider({
     animation: "slide",
     smoothHeight: true
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameter to add to your JQuery Flexslider call:

```
useCSS: false
```

Also visit this link issue discussed more through 
[here](https://github.com/woocommerce/FlexSlider/issues/345)!